# HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled in multiwindow mode

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, dagger-2

Every thing is working fine I am facing below error when my app goes to `onPause` state and then to `onResume` and when I call any API I get below error.

> HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled

I am using RxJava and Retrofit to do all my network operations. Below is my setup.

ApplicationComponent.java

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ContextModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);
}
```

ApplicationScope.java

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
  public @interface ApplicationScope {
}
```

ContextModule.java

```
@Module
public class ContextModule {

    private Context context;

    public ContextModule(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    public Context applicationContext(){
        return context.getApplicationContext();
    }

}
```

NetworkModule.java

```
@Module @ApplicationScope
public class NetworkModule {

    private final String BASE_CONTACT_URL = "";

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public PoolAPIService getPoolApiService(Retrofit retrofit){
        APIServiceapiServicece = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        return apiServicece;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public Retrofit getRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_CONTACT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)

                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor, Cache cache){
        OkHttpClient okhttpclient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
        return okhttpclient;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public HttpLoggingInterceptor getInterceptor(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                Log.d("Log", message);
            }
        });
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public Cache getCache(File cacheFile){
        Cache cache = new Cache(cacheFile, 10*1024*1024); //10MB size
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public File getCacheFile(Context context){
        File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "cache");
        cacheFile.mkdirs();
        return cacheFile;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    public Picasso getPicasso(Context context, OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient))
                .build();
        return picasso;
    }

}
```

I am injecting it in my Application class.

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;
    @Inject
    APIService apiService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .build();

        applicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public APIService getAPIService(){
        return apiService;
    }

}
```

And this is how I am calling the API Service.

LoginActivity.java

```
//creating LoginService instance
LoginService loginService = new LoginService(((MyApplication)getApplication()).getAPIService());

.......

void login() {
        final String mobileNumber = view.getMobileNumber();
        final String password = view.getPassword();

        Subscriber<LoginResponse> subscriber = new Subscriber<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted");
                if(subscriptionLogin != null && !subscriptionLogin.isUnsubscribed()){
                    subscriptionLogin.unsubscribe();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
                Log.d(TAG, loginResponse.message);
            }
        };


        LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
        request.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        request.password = password;

        subscriptionLogin = service.login(subscriber, request);

        compositeSubscription.add(subscriptionLogin);

 ....

  void onDestroy() {
    //unsubscribe all the subscription
    compositeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Logcat

```
--> POST http://.../.. http/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 32
--> END POST (32-byte body)
<-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
```

Comment: What do you do with `compositeSubscription`?

Comment: Please post full error stacktrace

Comment: what are you doing at onPause() and onResume()?

Comment: @yosriz nothing relating to retrofit or rxjava

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've logged `onStart`, `onResume`, `onPause` and `onStop`. Here's the output when activity enters multi-window mode:

[image]

I bet you haven't expected that after `onResume` immediately `onPause` will be called. And, as long as you are creating a subscription in `onResume` it is reasonable for you to unsubscribe in `onPause`, which happens immediately.

> HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled

This means, that you have unsubscribed from your subscription (i.e. your retrofit call is cancelled).

Comment: there was compositeSubscription.unsubscribe() in onStop as well. Thanks for making me look in the right direction.

Comment: @ik024, welcome. Unexpected behaviour, at least for me.